# different output using stringi and gsub (using the same pattern on the same string)

Tags: r, gsub, stringi

I wish to know why I obtain two different output strings by using gsub and stringi. Does the metacharacter "." not include new lines in stringi? Does stringi read "line by line"?

By the way I did not find any way to perform the "correct" substitution with stringi so I needed to use gsub here.

```
string <- "is it normal?\n\nhttp://www.20minutes.fr"

> gsub(" .*?http"," http", string)
[1] "is http://www.20minutes.fr"

> stri_replace_all_regex(string, " .*?http"," http")
[1] "is it normal?\n\nhttp://www.20minutes.fr"
```

Comment: Try `stri_replace_all_regex(string, " .*?http"," http", opts_regex = stri_opts_regex(dotall = TRUE))`.

Comment: @lukeA I think you could post the comment as an answer

Comment: yep. By the way also this works: `stri_replace_all_regex(string, "(?s) .*?http"," http")` By the way I consider this behaviour weird!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to set `.` to also match line terminators instead of stopping at a line:

```
stri_replace_all_regex(string, " .*?http"," http", 
                       opts_regex = stri_opts_regex(dotall = TRUE))
```

Comment: Do you know why they changed the standard R (posix) regex behaviour? Is it in Perl that the dot does not match new lines?

Answer (score 2):

By default -- for historical reasons, see [this tutorial](http://regular-expressions.info/dot.html) -- in most regex engines a dot doesn't match a newline character.
As @lukeA suggested, to match a newline you may set `dotall` option to `TRUE` in stringi regex-based functions.

By the way, `gsub(..., perl=TRUE)` gives results consistent with stringi.